# How can i open a Network port in Jmeter and wait for a response from application server

Tags: jmeter

I have a Requirement, where i need to open up a Network Port of my client machine and wait for a Response to get from that port from application serve. 
Can you please help about how to open up a network Port in jmeter

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "open" port, all ports of your operating system are already "open" (if something is not listening on them or they are not blocked by [operating system firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)))

Anyway, you can do this only using [Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html) class from one of the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

An example simple minimalistic code which opens port `1234`, listens for incoming messages and prints them to *jmeter.log* file would look like:

```
def server = new ServerSocket(1234)

while(true) {
    server.accept { socket ->
        log.info('Someone is connected')
        socket.withStreams { input, output ->
            def line = input.newReader().readLine()
            log.info('Received message: ' + line)
        }
        log.info("Connection processed")
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter incoming connection socket implementation]

Just in case if it goes too fast for you: I'm sending `Hello` message to JMeter using telnet client and it writes this down to the log file:

[image: JMeter Groovy Sockets Demo]

You may also want to check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.